# How do I return this function with a dollar sign before it. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I am making a converter for different prices based on varients, I am in the beginning stages, I wanted to know how to add a dollar sign before the number outputs.

```js
 function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (x * .97).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
 }
```

```html
<input id="myText" placeholder="$149,995.00" type="number">
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Convert</button>
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are expecting

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  var amount = (x * .97).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "$" + amount;
 }
```

```html
<input id="myText" placeholder="$149,995.00" type="number">
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Convert</button>
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
```

Comment: @JacobPink if its helpful please mark as answer and do upvote, Thanks

Comment: How would I add a dollar sign in the input once you start typing something? @JayVaghasiya

Comment: @JacobPink you can not add string into input type number

Answer (score 1):

```js
 function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "$"+(x * .97).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
 }
```

```html
<input id="myText" placeholder="$149,995.00" type="number">
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Convert</button>
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `"$" +` in the front:

```js
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  "$" + (x * .97).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
 }
```

```html
<input id="myText" placeholder="$149,995.00" type="number">
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Convert</button>
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
```